# Salesforce SOSL: match ids to master-detail fields

Tags: salesforce

Ladies and Gents, I have created a junction object (name_*CallContactMap*_c) that describes a many:many relationship between a custom object (call) and Contact. The object has 2 master-detail fields, one refers to a contact record and one to my custom call record. I am hoping that a call like this will work:

```
FIND {a0AA0000007MJkhMAG} RETURNING
    name__CallContactMap__c(name__Contact__r.FirstName,name__Contact__r.LastName)
```

As it stands the call returns zero records and no error. There is definitely a matching record. Needless to say I can find it using SOQL, but it's the "scanning all objects at once" feature in SOSL that I want to use as there will be many different junction objects linking to many different kinds of object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_sosl.htm)

> SOSL enables you to search text, email, and phone fields for multiple objects simultaneously

The limitation you're hitting is that id fields are not considered text fields.  That said your approach can work if you mirror the record id in a text field which would then be accessible in SOSL searches.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot search on Id's using SOSL at the moment. You can use a SOQL to search for the the junction object. Would be curious to know why you prefer to use SOSL instead of SOQL?

- Anup

Comment: Hi Anup - the reason is that I want the call to be assignable to many different types of object simultaneously, and SOSL allows me to pick different fields for the different object types in a single call.